# Render a timer component onClick

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend

I have a Timer component in a returned from a TimerContainer

```
const Timer = ({ time = 0 }) => (
 <div className={styles.timer}>{formatTime(time)}</div>
);

Timer.propTypes = {
  time: PropTypes.number
};

class TimerContainer extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      secondsElapsed: 0
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.interval = setInterval(this.tick.bind(this), 1000);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    clearInterval(this.interval);
  }

  tick() {
    this.setState({
      secondsElapsed: this.state.secondsElapsed + 1
    });
  }

  render() {
    return <Timer time={this.state.secondsElapsed} />;
  }
}
```

How do I get it to only start when I click on another Button component? In my main component I have two functions for the Buttons

```
handleEasyCards() {
    this.setState(prevState => ({ currentCards: this.state.easyCards }));
  }

  handleHardCards() {
    this.setState({ currentCards: this.state.hardCards });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div style={boardContainer}>
        <div style={buttonContainer}>
          <Button
            difficulty={this.state.easyButton}
            onClick={this.handleEasyCards}
          />
          <Button
            difficulty={this.state.hardButton}
            onClick={this.handleHardCards}
          />
        </div>
        <Cards
          cardTypes={this.state.currentCards}
          removeMatches={this.removeMatches}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

I think I need to pass a callback to the Button component and call it in the handleHardCards and handleEasyCards. I don't think this is a conditional render because the Timer will start with either Button clicked.

Comment: Can you try making a codesandbox.io example and I'll take a look?

Comment: Presumably the Button and TimerContainer share a parent component -- you want to pass a method from the parent to the Button called something like "startTimer()". Regardless, would be easier to represent in a CodeSandbox as @ColinRicardo mentioned

Comment: Here it is..[Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/ly4rzzvjyl). The main component is Game.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could have another variable in the state:

```
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      secondsElapsed: 0,
      isCountingTime: false,
    };
  }
```

Then change that variable when an event happen:

```
handleEasyCards() {
  this.setState(prevState => ({ 
    currentCards: this.state.easyCards,
    isCountingTime: true,
  }));
}

handleHardCards() {
  this.setState({ 
    currentCards: this.state.hardCards,
    isCountingTime: true,
  });
}
```

Until now `Timer` has not been mounted so have not started counting. But with `isCountingTime` set to `true` it will render and start counting:

```
<div style={boardContainer}>
  {this.state.isCountingTime && <Timer />}
  ...
</div>
```

The good part is that you can "start" and "reset" Timer whenever you want just by changing `isCountingTime` variable to `true`. The bad part is that nothing is rendered (no default values) when is set to `false`.

Comment: That worked and I think to stop it and capture the time elapsed, a conditional render would be needed when there are no cards left on the board. I think I need to have another state property to get updated every tick and then render that when the game is done. Am i on the right track?

Comment: @KevinT. Yep, I think no matter what strategy you would choose if you want parent component to "know" about the time, you will need some callback like `onTimeChange` passed to Timer and store that value in Parent state.